# Anyway to group counts in MSSQL rows-columns which have similar names. For eg. Cisco, Cisco Systems & Cisco Systems Inc.?

Tags: php, html, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'm trying to count devices by MAC vendors prefixes on a network. The results from the queries I'm getting back from the database have the counts but the names of vendors differ slightly like Cisco, Cisco Systems & Cisco Systems Inc. Is there anyway to add all of these and represent them as just Cisco ?

I'll be displaying this information on a web front end. I am using PHP to retrieve data from this database.

Cisco is just an example here. It could be any other MAC vendor with different lengths of name.

Comment: Can we assume that you already have a function that will decide what makes names "similar," and the question is just whether you can use that in a GROUP BY?

Comment: @octern - No, that's the problem. I need to find a way to decide how I can decide what names are similar. But the way of a functions seems a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

```
select substring(caseID,1,5), count(*) 
from docSVsys 
group by substring(caseID,1,5)
```

Comment: substring starts at position 1.  So, I think you meant substring (caseID,1,5).

Comment: Actually this won't work, since Cisco was just an example. It could be any other MAC vendor name with different lengths.

Comment: Are they separated by a space?  Could you do `substring(caseID, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', caseID))`?

Comment: I like that idea @TedSpence, but to handle strings with no space maybe it should be `substring(caseID, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ',caseID),0),LEN(CaseID)))`.

Comment: Actually, this is simpler: `substring(caseID, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',caseID+' ')-1)`

Comment: Then that was a problem with the question not the answer and yet not even an up tick.  You are welcome.

Comment: @GilM nice addition!  I like that trick.  I imagine next we'll learn that the original source data is separated by pipe symbols instead ;)